# SharePointContextProvider not found when Creating a provider hosted app with VS2015

Tags: csom, provider-hosted-app, mvc, visual-studio-2015

I try to create a provider hosted app (MVC) with VS2015.

I use the standard template-approach like described there: http://chakkaradeep.com/index.php/building-apps-for-sharepoint-with-mvc/
(Or many other places like msdn)

After that project is created, I receive an error that *SharePointContextProvider* and *SharePointContextFilter* can not be found. ("missing assembly reference")

I run VS as administrator and have already installed the "Windows Identity Foundation SDK", "SharePoint Client Components SDK" and the "Azure SDK"

Is there a nuget package or something like that I have to add to my project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need go add [OfficeDev PnP Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=officedev) in your project. Depending on if you're developing for online or on-premise.

Comment: Thx. I cannot believe I did Google that issue for HOURS and did not find that solution.

Comment: hi, any idea how can we add the package